# Xpath and XSLT to display selected data to html

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi I am creating XSLT for xml I have to create Xpath query to search for stop and display in html format and display stop number, name, location (latitude&longitude), and route number.

I just want to ask is my XSLT and Xpath Query is right

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="body">
        <table style="width:720px" border="3">
          <tr>
            <th>
              <font face="Verdana" size="4">ltc Stop in </font>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//stop[name='']/name"/>
        </table>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<allstops>
  <stop number="2504" name="Main &amp; Bainard EB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.91033567</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.29671483</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>28</routes>
  </stop>
  <stop number="20" name="Adelaide &amp; Ada NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9742886</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2252341</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
  </stop>
  <stop number="22" name="Adelaide &amp; Central Ave NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9945666</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2343441</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
  </stop>
```

Comment: It doesn't look right based on what you've provided; you are trying to reference `name` without using `@name`. In order to provide a good answer can you supply a sample of the html output you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason stated your Xpath is referencing a location that doesn't exist in the XML, there is no `name` node, just an attribute which would have caused issues.

What you likely want to do is find all the stops and process those, so you can just go `//stop` to do this. Also, its bad practise to use deprecated tags, like `font` so I've removed those.

Below is an example XSLT that might help get you started.

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="body">
        <table style="width:720px" border="3">
      <tr>
            <td>Stop #</td>
            <td>Route #</td>
            <td>Name</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//stop"/>
        </table>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="stop">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="routes"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

## XML:

```
<allstops>
  <stop number="2504" name="Main and Bainard EB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.91033567</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.29671483</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>28</routes>
  </stop>
  <stop number="20" name="Adelaide and  Ada NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9742886</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2252341</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
  </stop>
  <stop number="22" name="Adelaide and Central Ave NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9945666</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2343441</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
  </stop>
</allstops>
```

## Output:

```
<html>
<body>
<table style="width:720px" border="3">
<tr>
<td>Stop #</td>
<td>Route #</td>
<td>Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2504</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>Main and Bainard EB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>Adelaide and  Ada NB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>Adelaide and Central Ave NB</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

## Example output:

[image: example table]